# can serenity js used as a testing tool for Knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js, serenity-js

I want to know whether the serenity/js can be used for other JavaScript frameworks or it just only for Angular/js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is a wrapper around Selenium WebDriver, which means that it can test anything WebDriver could.

To test any non-Angular project though you'll need to disable Angular-specific test synchronisation, which you can do using either:

## Protractor configuration file

If your tests are only ever going to execute non-Angular projects, you can disable Angular-specific synchronisation for all the tests by adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to the `onPrepare` block in your protractor.conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  // ... other config

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;  // <-- disables synchronisation
  }
};
```

## Serenity/JS task

If your tests need to support both Angular and non-Angular projects, you can toggle the synchronisation using the `UseAngular.disableSynchronisation()` and `UseAngular.enableSynchronisation()` tasks like this:

```
actor.attemptsTo(
  UseAngular.disableSynchronisation(),
  // ... interact with a non-Angular app
  UseAngular.enableSynchronisation(),
  // ... interact with an Angular app
)
```

You can learn more about the second approach in my article on "[Cross-application testing](https://janmolak.com/cross-application-testing-with-serenity-js-4103a272b75b)"

If this answer helps, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thank you!

Comment: Thanks! As I know Serenity supports mocha, is there any way to use Jasmine with serenity?

Comment: Not yet, I'm afraid. The reporting information provided by Jasmine is quite rudimentary compared to Mocha, which makes writing custom reporters a bit more tricky. Also, Jasmine doesn't seem to support promise-based asynchronous tests and requires you to explicitly call the `done` callback, which is also better handled in Mocha. This being said, if there's a huge demand for Jasmine support (or a nice pull request ;-) ) I'd be happy to add it in.